# Error Using DbExecutionStrategy About Streaming but Streaming not used

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use a custom DbExecutionStrategy that implements retries, but I'm getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Streaming queries are not supported by the configured execution strategy 'MyDbExecutionStrategy'. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=309381 for additional information.

If you follow that link it will explain that EF6 doesn't use streaming by default but that you can turn it on by using AsStreaming().

> By default, EF6 and later version will buffer query results rather than streaming them. If you want to have results streamed you can use the AsStreaming method to change a LINQ to Entities query to streaming.

However, the call that is being made does not use streaming and I don't have any code that calls AsStreaming().

```
dataModel.Set<DeploymentLog>().OrderByDescending(d => d.DeploymentTimestamp).FirstOrDefault()
```

I've copied the code and the strategy to a different command line app that I created to test it and it works fine there. But in my web application I'm getting that error.

Any ideas why? Is there some kind of setting to turn on streaming on all queries?

Comment: Are you sure your MyDbExecutionStrategy returns true for "RetriesOnFailure" property? Because in current version of EF, streaming is enabled by default, unless execution strategy is used with RetriesOnFailure = true.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I went to check and I found that I was suspending my execution strategy using the workaround and had accidentally set the suspended = true which was causing the error.